# Inverted brightness button

Tags: display, brightness, backlight

I use the last Ubuntu version (18.10) on my laptop (Compaq 15-s020nf) and the brightness button are inverted.
I got the same behavior when I control the backlight with the command line:

```
echo 1000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness  # I got a bright screen
echo 6000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness  # I got a dark screen
```

Do you have any advice to resolve that ?

Comment: I dont have a solution, but do your volume up/down buttons work correctly? You could look into acpi settings, I know I had some issues with the brightness settings when messing with it.

Other than that check out some bug reports, I know of some people that had the same issues in past Ubuntu version.

Comment: Sound button are fine. I started Ubuntu with `acpi=off` but there's no change. Thanks for the suggestion: I will look into the bug reports.

Comment: Hey @j6tron  i have same problem with my laptop. have you fixed till now?

Comment: @Devang Hingu  No, the laptop screen is broken. I do not use this laptop anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it on my HP 15 notebook.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` file.

Add `i915.invert_brightness=1` to the `"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT"` (as I did in the following screenshot).

[image: screenshot]

Run `sudo update-grub2` (or `sudo update-grub`) and reboot.